# Why does my Vue.js app not run when I use the runtime version of Vue?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I have changed my Vue.js version to the runtime version by modifying Webpack as follows:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.js'
      // 'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
```

The commented out version is what I previously used, and my app worked. Here is my Vue.js code (which previously worked):

```
import Forgot from "./components/Forgot.vue";
import Vue from "vue";

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: {
        Forgot
    },
    data: {
        email: ""
    }
});
```

Under the runtime version of Vue.js, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n(...).default is not a constructor
```

and Chrome DevTools isolates the error to the following line:

```
new Vue({
```

Why doesn't my code work under the runtime version of Vue?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the official documentation (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Explanation-of-Different-Builds) you will find a description about the different builds. So you are trying to use an UMD build (which is supposed to run in browser - not to be transformed by Webpack) in an ES environment. You should try `vue.runtime.esm.js` instead. By the way if you do not configure an alias for `vue$` it should automatically pickup the right one - `vue.runtime.esm.js`